# What does batch_size mean in Keras' TimeSeriesGenerator?

Tags: python, keras

I'm working with a video classification of 5 classes and using TimeDistributed CNN model. The train dataset contains 8 videos containing 75 frames each.I have used TimeSeriesGenerator of Keras where length equals 75 as each video contains 75 sequences.But, it seems unclear to me what batch_size should be in this case.

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
train_sequences = TimeseriesGenerator(train_data, train_labels, length=75, batch_size=1)
```

Can anyone tell me what batch size should be considered for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batch size defines the number of video samples that will be introduce in each iteration of your model. The difference between the different values of batch size are the model weight's optimization. If batch size is equal to 3, the model will input the 3 sample videos and only after that 3 inputs, it will update the weights.

There isn't a optimal value for batch size. It's like No Free Lunch Theorem. I suggest you to try different values and look for the best results.

There are constraint in defining the batch size:

- If the value is small, it will require less memory and it could be faster, since your model is requesting fewer samples. Otherwise, the gradient estimation will be less accurate.
- If the value is big, the gradient's estimation will be more accurate, but it will need more memory and could be slower.

So you have to find a optimal value between grandient's estimation accuracy and computational resources usage

Comment: That means if I have a dataset of 500 videos, and if I assign 64 to batch_size,  64 video samples will be introduced in each iteration of my model, right?